# Installing all ros dependencies of a single package rather than the entire workspace

Tags: ros, rosdep, catkin, ros-kinetic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to run something like rosdep install package and have it traverse the list of packages that it depends and install all system and distribution dependencies

Example of my situation

- package_b depends on package_a
- package_c depends on package_a
- package_a depends on system_dependency_e
- package_b depends on system_dependency_f

I want to execute something like

rosdep install package_a --some-commands

and install a, b, e, and f

However when I execute that rosdep install always returns something like

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
package_b: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [package_a]
```

But when I run

rosdep install -i package_b

It only installs b and f

My workaround is to do

```
rosdep install -i $(rospack depends package_a)
```

But rospack requires all files to be in $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

and $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH only gets generated when the workspace is sourced

and the workspace is only sourced after you build the workspace

Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327733/installing-all-ros-dependencies-of-a-single-package-rather-than-the-entire-workspace/) by [vuwij1](https://answers.ros.org/users/43969/vuwij1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-05**:
Do I understand you correctly when I believe that #q326140 is asking for the same thing ("How to rosdep install dependencies of one package?")? Does the work-around I posted there not work for you?

**Comment by [vuwij1](https://answers.ros.org/users/43969/vuwij1/) on 2019-07-11**:
Well that seems a bit too hardcoded. I was hoping for a automatic way to add all rospackages into the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH without having to manually type, and my question was asking if foo depends on bar, to install all packages for both foo and bar, rather than just foo. But not including the rest of the packages in the workspace

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-11**:\

> I was hoping for a automatic way to add all rospackages into the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH without having to manually type

I'm not sure I understand: whatever is added to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` will be crawled *recursively*. You only need to add the `src` space of the workspace, not each and every pkg individually.

> my question was asking if foo depends on bar, to install all packages for both foo and bar, rather than just foo. But not including the rest of the packages in the workspace

So you want `rosdep` to install all dependencies of `foo`, recursively, including those of `bar`, but only if `foo` depends on `bar` somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So what about a combination of what you show here and #q326140?

Something like:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/your/catkin_ws/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH \
  rosdep install -i $(rospack depends package_a)
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vuwij1](https://answers.ros.org/users/43969/vuwij1/) on 2019-07-11**:
I see this answers my question. the thing i didn't know is that ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is crawled recursively. Thank you!